# Not able to run multiple WDIO commands in one line

Tags: shell, command-line-interface, webdriver-io

I have two configs which I would like to run one after another. I am doing the following

```
environment=staging npx wdio run ./e2e/wdio.regression.grid.conf.js && environment=staging npx wdio run ./e2e/wdio.smoke.grid.conf.js
```

This works fine when the first config passes and will proceed to next. In case there is failure on any test while running first config, the execution gets ended.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run both commands even if the first command fails, you have to use the semicolon.

> The semicolon (;) operator allows you to execute multiple commands in
> succession, regardless of whether each previous command succeeds.

As such, you commands becomes:

```
environment=staging npx wdio run ./e2e/wdio.regression.grid.conf.js ; environment=staging npx wdio run ./e2e/wdio.smoke.grid.conf.js
```

The logical AND operator (`&&`) will run the second command only if the first command is successful.

Comment: Thanks for the response., I tried with ; and still it is the same. The second config is not getting executed